# seekTo, playVideo, and pauseVideo functions not working in YouTube Player API

Tags: javascript, html, api, youtube

I'm working with the YouTube Player API and using the `seekTo()` function, but it doesn't work. In fact, `playVideo()` or `pauseVideo()` doesn't work too. Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="swfobject.js"></script>
<body>
<div id="divvideo">
<p>You will need Flash 8 or better to view this content.</p>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var params = { allowScriptAccess: "always" };
    var atts = { id: "video" };
    swfobject.embedSWF(
        "http://www.youtube.com/v/o3nmOw9vKw4?enablejsapi=1&playerapiid=video", "divvideo", "720", "405", "8", null, null, params, atts);

ytplayer = document.getElementById("video");

function play() {
    if (ytplayer) {
        ytplayer.playVideo();
    }

}
</script>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="play()">Play</a>
</body>
```

The video appears, but the Play hyperlink doesn't work. What should I do?

Comment: So it's particularly the scripting that doesn't work? Or does the player itself not work? Do you have any value for ytplayer?

Comment: It's the scripting: the player works, but when I press the "Play" hyperlink, it does nothing. I think ytplayer is the object who appears: ytplayer = document.getElementById("video");

Answer (score 2):

In your JavaScript, you have this:

```
ytplayer = document.getElementById("video");
```

But when you declare your element, you declare it like this:

```
<div id="divvideo">
```

See the mismatch? You're looking for an HTML element whose `id` is `"video"`, but there isn't one -- your HTML element's `id` is `"divvideo"` instead.

You need to either change your `getElementById` call to take `"divvideo"`, or else change your `div` to have `id="video"`.

Comment: No, #video is the name of the <object> or <embed> who appears using SWFObject. I tried changing document.getElementById("divvideo"), but it doesn't work. But thanks for spending your time! ;-).